# WP7 socket response "Connection Reset" when running on device

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, sockets, usb, zune

I'm really having a hard time with this problem:

- I connect the socket to the server's ip and port
- wait until I receive a *success* message
- call send() function to send a packet to the server
- receive() function returns "*Connection Reset*" and nothing reached the server

On emulator everything is working fine, and I'm connecting the device using a usb cable and Zune is launching normally.

Any ideas?

Comment: `receive()` functions don't "return 'Connection reset by peer'". Do you mean it returned -1 with `errno==ECONNRESET`? or threw an exception with that message? that partial message? that *name?* Please be specific. Paste the *actual error message* into your post.

Comment: yes it returned this string : ConnectionReset

Comment: NO answer ??? come on! I need the usb cable for debugging